# Coin transaction not showing in Pinklock wallet

Tags: erc-20, etherscan

I'm trying to help my friends sort out an issue for why the coin supply they locked/sent to Pinklock v2 wallet aren't showing up in said wallet.

this is the txn: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xccebb02c9fba6ec9c7caf6016f3cd308e94cf9bcfe86126b62d26be04bc0e54e

This is the pinklock wallet: 0x71b5759d73262fbb223956913ecf4ecc51057641

As you can see, the transaction was successful, yet Etherscan doesn't see the tokens in that Pinklock wallet. Anyone know why? Does the Pinklock wallet custodian have to manually import the tokens or something? Another weird thing is that Dextools see's the locked supply, yet the Marketcap is incorrect. It's like the various systems aren't handshaking correctly.

https://www.dextools.io/app/en/ether/pair-explorer/0x40467790c458d51085d8019c9389c5ebf7e48002

EJ

Comment: Some of the tokens are there. That wallet has a lot of token, perhaps etherscan isn't showing all of them.